# When should I write an HTML helper as an extension method instead of a simple static method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

There are two ways of creating a custom HTML helper in ASP.NET MVC:

1. You can create a class with a static method that outputs HTML, or
2. You can add an extension method to the HtmlHelper class.

Option #1 seems simpler and easier.

- What's the advantage to Option #2?
- When would I want to do that instead of Option #1?
- Does Option #2 give you any sort of benefit or added features?

Edited to add :

In this particular situation, I'm trying to output a string that's formed through a bunch of conditional logic.  It seems wrong to put this in my model, but doing it all in Razor seems tedious and unnecessary -- or am I wrong about that?

Comment: There's a third option and the one I would recommend you: use ViewModels and Display\Editor Templates. That way you're not breaking the pattern. All that is HTML stays in the Views, without writing code through extensions and/or static methods.

Comment: Check [this](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) post for more information on how to do it. That's the correct way of doing what you're about to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On our current project we started by doing lots of HtmlHelper extensions but we realize that's just the wrong thing to do, mostly because:

- It breaks the pattern because you're writing HTML through C# code, outside the Views.
- It's not validation friendly at all!!

So we simply throw out almost all of those helpers and we've implemented ViewModels and Templates for all of the controllers. That's the correct way of doing it.

This is the best place to start: [ASP.NET MVC 2 Templates, Part 1: Introduction](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html)

Bottom line, if you're building HTML through code, something is wrong with your project's logic/pattern.

Comment: I get what you're saying about why HTMLHelpers are bad.... but having looked at Templates, I don't see how they can help me in this particular situation, where I'm trying to output a string (with some HTML) that was created through a bunch of conditional logic.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding?

Comment: The place for that logic is in the controller. To the view you just pass data that needs very few or (ideally) no logic at all. Forget ViewBag\ViewData. Pass all your data to the View through ViewModels and display them through DisplayTemplates. Believe me, you will thank in the long-term.

Comment: Interesting!  I hadn't thought about putting the string-building logic into the controller.  I think I'll give that a shot and see how it turns out.  Thanks!

Comment: I have everything for a custom form element worked out using viewmodels and templates, except how to bloody add an arbitrary HTML attribute to the element via my validation attribute, so am forced to look toward a helper rather, where I am not limited.

Answer (score 0):

I find the option 2 much cleaner to write HTML as it is separated from C# code. And in actual razor views where you are supposed to put your HTML.

This is assuming you are talking about @helper syntax in razor

Comment: I'm not sure we're talking about the same thing.  All the examples I've seen look like this :

<%= Html.MethodName("arg1", "arg2") %>